# How to setup multidatabase in symfony doctrine

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine

i am using symfony for my project where i have two database, 
but i know only to setup symfony for single database, like below code
database.yml

```
all:doctrine:
class: sfDoctrineDatabase
param:
  dsn:      mysql:host=localhost;dbname=gapi
  username: root
  password:
```

so, please help me about to setup two or more database for symfony doctrine.

Answer (score 2):

The structure of the `databases.yml` is like this:

```
all: # <-- Environment
  doctrine: # <-- Name of connection
    class: sfDoctrineDatabase # <-- Connection class
    param: # <-- Parameters for the class
      dsn:      mysql:host=localhost;dbname=gapi
      username: root
      password:
```

So if you want to add an extra database connection (the `databases.yml  specifies the connections, not the databases itself). You can copy the block from`doctrine` on, and give it a new name. Something like this:

```
all: # <-- Environment
  doctrine: # <-- Name of connection
    class: sfDoctrineDatabase # <-- Connection class
    param: # <-- Parameters for the class
      dsn:      mysql:host=localhost;dbname=gapi
      username: root
      password: 

  # Extra connection:
  connection2: # <-- Name of connection
    class: sfDoctrineDatabase # <-- Connection class
    param: # <-- Parameters for the class
      dsn:      mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database2
      username: root
      password:
```

But be warned: working with multiple connections requires a lot of understanding of Symfony and Doctrine, and you have think and test very good, to know for sure you're executing queries on the correct connection.

Comment: thanks for answer, but now how to create schema.yml for specific database. please help

Comment: You can specify a connection in the table options section of your yml.